# recursion in graphql using golang

Tags: go, recursion, graphql

i am using https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen in golang for graphql, want to create an api that returns tree like structure, however i want to give a depth control instead of writing nested selections in the queries. is there a way to achieve this?
Want to achieve some thing like this,

```
query listAll{
  node: getNodes(parentId: "1235") {
    ID
    Name
    node: Children @recursive(depth: 10) {
        ID
        Name
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

GraphQL has a principle for explicitly asking for what you need; it has no "recurse" directive. In other words, if you want nodes to the depth of 10, you'll have to write a query with 10 nestings. Obviously you can generate the text of the query from your program to be whatever you wish, dynamically.

If you're worried about the potential complexity of these queries and how much data they can demand, check out gqlgen's `FixedComplexityLimit` extension as described in the [documentation](https://gqlgen.com/reference/complexity/#limiting-query-complexity).

```
func main() {
    c := Config{ Resolvers: &resolvers{} }
        srv := handler.NewDefaultServer(blog.NewExecutableSchema(c))
        srv.Use(extension.FixedComplexityLimit(5)) // This line is key
    r.Handle("/query", srv)
}
```

Comment: thanks. i understood the GraphQL principle, however, i got curious after seeing a comment https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/91#issuecomment-487320203 and was thinking if this still can be achieved ....

Comment: @karts to the best of my knowledge gqlgen doesn't support this

Comment: how do i model the usecase where i need to return a tree with all the elements that matches input filter criteria but the depth is unknown? I wil not be able to write a query with nestings for this.

Comment: @karts You cannot ask it to return a whole tree, to the best of my knowledge, or maybe you could represent the whole tree in some custom type.

Comment: can u suggest how do i model this using custom type? you meant use interfaces for child nodes?